# How to make a bar graph with groups and multiple variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this data frame here

```
structure(list(time = c("Time0", "Time1", "Time2", "Time0", "Time1", "Time2"), DASS_stress = c(10, 
12, 16, NA_real_, 0, NA_real_), DASS_anx = c(6, 
NA_real_, 5, 14, NA_real_, 10), DASS_depr = c(5, 
6, NA_real_, 6, 11, NA_real_)), row.names = c("3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to make a barplot for all three time points of Pre, Post, and Follow-Up for the three variables of DASS_stress, DASS_anx, and DASS_depr.

Specifically, I'm looking to include just the means of those DASS scales. I've tried to make a graph using ggplot

```
ggplot(data=DASS, aes(x=time, y=DASS_stress, fill=time)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

This didn't give me what I needed as it was not the mean and I was missing the two other scales. I know I need to reorganize my data and get the means for each specific time point (i.e. Pre, Post, Follow-Up).
I run into troubles with colMeans where I get the error of "x must be an array of at least two dimensions". So I tried the basic mean function.

```
DASS$Stress <- mean(DASS$time=='Pre' & DASS$DASS_stress, na.rm=TRUE)
```

The basic mean function gives me the issue of just one column of all the data with incorrect means and not the mean for just Pre.

Any tips for this?

Comment: What is `SCAREDC_T`?

Comment: Oh wait I gave the wrong example. Fixing it now.

Comment: Fixed it. SCAREDC_T was from a different attempt which went nowhere. It doesn't involve the dataframe I'm working with right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think reshaping to a "long" format then summarizing works well.

```r
DASS %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("DASS_"), names_to = "DASS", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(time, DASS) %>%
  summarize(
    n = sum(!is.na(val)), 
    mu = mean(val, na.rm = TRUE), 
    se = sd(val, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(n), 
    ci = se * qt(0.95/2 + 0.5, n-1)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DASS, y = mu, fill = time)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mu-se, ymax = mu+se), 
                  position = position_dodge(.9), width = 0.3)
# Warning in qt(0.95/2 + 0.5, n - 1) : NaNs produced
# Warning in qt(0.95/2 + 0.5, n - 1) : NaNs produced
# Warning in qt(0.95/2 + 0.5, n - 1) : NaNs produced
# Warning in qt(0.95/2 + 0.5, n - 1) : NaNs produced
# Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image: ggplot2, dodged, with errorbars]

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even think about trying to use summarize. I think this will help immensely. My thought process was stuck on making the data frame larger with separate mean columns. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I have one issue: for me the fill=time is giving me an error. It says the "aesthetic must be valid data columns". It won't work in my case. Going to try to debug this.

Comment: My actual DF has about 741 entries in it. I couldn't post it all in here using dput. You think that could be my issue? Not sure since I'm getting a very specific error involving fill=.

Comment: Figured out the issue: ```plyr::summarize``` was being used instead of ```dplyr::summarize```. I just had to explicitly tell R to use ```dplyr::summarize```. Thanks for the help.